# Battery - high capacity but low power

Tags: batteries, amperage, watts

I recently saw an advertisement for a battery with 50,000mAh storage capacity, with an output of 5V and 10W power.

Is this even possible? Shouldn't it be 250W power, or did I misunderstand things?

I wish I could show the ad but it's on Youtube and since it's kind of a habit to click "Skip Ad," I didn't quite notice. I am 100% sure it's written and voiced as such.

Comment: I don't see any contradiction here. Why do you think it should be 250 watt?

Comment: 5V at 10W means it can output 2A (=10W / 5V) at a time, out of a “reservoir” of 50Ah of battery capacity (=50.000mAh, note the “h” which stands for hours). The size of the reservoir has nothing to do with how much it can output at any given moment.

Comment: So is it still correct to say the battery have 250Wh (or 0.25 kWh) "reservoir"?

Comment: Adding a link to the video as well as details is fully acceptable. Issues include chemistry/ type , voltage, intended use more.

Comment: Many cells are rated at C or C/2 capacity (1 or 2 hour rate) but some at C/10. 5Ah at C/10 is 0.5 A X 5V = 2.5 W so 10 W = 2A = 0.4 C = reasonable.

Comment: 5V output at 2A is quite common for USB chargers and the like; the 5V is generated by a DC-DC from a lithium cell that operates at around 4V.  In this case the current is limited by the DC-DC converter, the cell itself is probably capable of more current than that.  The total capacity is claimed to be 50Ah, so it could supply 2A for around 20 hours, allowing for conversion losses.  I’d be dubious about the capacity claim though, 50Ah is a decent size for a car battery.

Answer (score 3):

For many battery technologies, battery capacity and battery power are mutually exclusive optimisations within that one technology.

The capacity of the battery depends on the volume of changeable material that stores charge, so more area and depth of the 'storage stuff' is good.

The power of the battery depends on the area and length of the current path, so the backing electrodes, the electrolyte, more surface area of the 'storage stuff' is good, and less depth is good.

The tradeoff comes mostly around volume dedicated to the storage stuff, versus the volume of backing electrodes, which don't store charge.

As such, you can optimise for a 'power' battery, or an 'energy' battery, but not both. Batteries tend to be rated at a 'C' discharge rate, 1C means they can discharge their capacity in an hour.

In the lithium world, most 18650's seem to be 'energy' batteries (maximum capacity for running laptops and cars for hours) with C ratings around one, while the prismatic RC model batteries seem to be designed to be able to dump all their energy in minutes into immensely powerful motors, some with discharge ratings of 30C or more.

It's a bit like a carpark for a big supermarket. If you have lots of lanes and exits, you can fill and empty fast, but there's not much room for cars. If you turn over some of the lanes and exits for more parking, more capacity, the rate at which you can fill and empty it is restricted by that extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

Capacity and power are different things. Both are connected with "voltage" and "time".

(Electrical) **capacity** (or charge) is current multiplied by time.

(Electrical) **power** is voltage multiplied by current.

Let's see:

- The (fixed) voltage is \$U = 5V\$.
- The maximum output power is \$P_{max} = 10W\$.
- The advertized capacity is \$Q = 50,000mAh = 50Ah\$.

The maximum output current is:
\$I_{max} = P_{max} / U = 10W / 5V = 2A\$

The minimum time the battery can source this current is:
\$t_{min} = Q / I_{max} = 50Ah / 2A = 25h\$

If your load takes less than the maximum current, the time will be longer. That's why this is the *minimum* time.

If you multiply voltage and capacity, you get the **energy**: \$E = U * Q = 5V * 50Ah = 250Wh\$

*Disclaimer: This is quite simplified to show the principles.*

Answer (score 0):

Big capacity and low power = long lifetime. That's all.

(BUT read the fine print : USB powerbanks are outrageous cheats; that 50Ah capacity (if it's even real, it must weigh about 1 kg) will be at the CELL voltage, 3.7V, giving 185Wh not at 5V giving 250Wh)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a normal secondary battery but a self recharging primary cell.  The specs do not indicate the self recharge time yet after a certain length of time perhaps a day, you can get up to 25W for a short period of time.

Look up Aluminum graphite cells
https://youtu.be/z0RU_ck64Bs